# Not understanding normalization when using ImageDataGenerator

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Im trying to build a simple image classifier using Keras with Tensorflow as backend. However im having a very hard time understanding how nomalization is done in Keras.

It is my understanding that in Machine Learning you calculate the mean and std of the training + validation set and then reuse the mean and std when normalizing the test set and when doing prediction on new data. So whit this in mind I will explain what Im not understanding in each part of Keras.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, samplewise_center=True, samplewise_std_normalization=True, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, samplewise_center=True, samplewise_std_normalization=True)
batch_size = 1024
train_generator = train_datagen.flow(X_train, one_hot_train_labels, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow(X_valid, one_hot_valid_labels, batch_size=batch_size)
```

First questions are with regards to `ImageDataGenerator`.
In the [documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) it says that the `flow` function normalizes the data, then I have tree questions regarding this:

1. What is the effect of `samplewise_std_normalization` and `samplewise_center` if it is the flow function that does the normalization?
2. Why use rescale if I also do normalization?
3. How can Keras do normalization on augmentad data that is generated at runtime so the mean and std is not know before start?

   result = model.evaluate(X_test, one_hot_test_labels)

When we run `evaluate` I have one question:

1. How is the normalization handled here? I dont have access to the mean and std so I cant apply them to also the testing set?

   predict_softmaxs = model.predict(np.array(resized_images))

When I run `predict` I have one question:

1. Again I dont have access to the mean and std so I cant apply it to the prediction image?

Answer (score 3):

> 1. What is the effect of samplewise_std_normalization and samplewise_center if it is the flow function that does the
>      normalization?

It's common practice to define transformers before you run them. For example `scikit-learn`'s transformers also do this (actually their `StandardScaler` works in an analogous way)

> 3. How can Keras do normalization on augmentad data that is generated at runtime so the mean and std is not know before start?

It can do batchtwise normalization.

It can be argued though that this is not correct way to standardize data. The correct way would be to standardize according to train set.
That means that you should first `fit` generator on train data, and only then use `flow` method.

This is actually baked in `ImageDataGenerator` - if you specify `samplewise_std_normalization` and do not fit your generator Keras will  [warn you](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/image.py#L593) when trying to standardize batch.

#### Evaluate and predict:

These are model's methods. They just run model on input data, so they don't do any normalization - you should feed data that was normalized before to them.

Comment: +1 for covering batch normalisation (which can reduce the need for drop out and results in faster network training). I’d just add that it’s normal to represent pixel values (normal range 0-255) in the range 0-1. So when you run your test data, you shouldn’t need to do anything with mean and std dev (whitening) but you DO need to make sure the pixel values are between 0 and 1. I think using pixel range 0-1 helps to reduce the required weights within the network and aids network convergence.

Comment: But the question remains, do i not need to mean and std of the training set for naormalizing the test set?

Comment: Yes, you should do that. I edited answer accordingly